# Difference between [A-Z] and LETTERS in grep

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to only keep rows whose id contains letters. And I find the following two ways give different results.

```
df[grep("[A-Z]",df$id),]
df[grep(LETTERS,df$id),]
```

It seems the second way will omit many rows that actually have letters.

Why?

Comment: becasue the `pattern` argument in `grep` is not vectorized. Hence it only looks for "A". Didn't you get a warning for your second line?

Comment: That might be the problem. I suppress all the warnings so I don't see it. What can I do if I want to grep patterns in a list? Like ["H',"a"]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to grep patterns in a vector try this:

```
to_match <- paste(LETTERS, collapse = "|")
to_match
[1] "A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z"
```

and then

```
df[grep(to_match, df$id), ]
```

Explanation: 
You will match any of the characters in "to_match" since they are separated by the "or" operator "|".